# Adding geodatabase connection from another PC to SQL server 2014?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql, server

I have a problem that I can not solve. I install SQl server 2014 and create Test1 database on My PC. Now I want to add Geodatabase connection in Arccatalog on Another PC. But it error below. 
Firewall and Antvirus is disable on my PC. Both of PC is also the same network.
I try:
 DESKTOP-1BB1A4S\SQL
 DESKTOP-1BB1A4S\SQL, 1433
 192.168.1.2\SQL, 1433

What do I do wrong?

Note: I can add connection on my PC.

[image]

Comment: The error message warns about client connectivity.  Did you install the matching client on the non-database machine?  Please edit your question to specify the release of ArcGIS being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the SQL Server Native Client so that your client machine (your PC) can talk to SQL Server.

> To connect to a database or geodatabase in SQL Server from ArcGIS for
>   Desktop, install the SQL Server native client on the ArcGIS for
>   Desktop computer and create a connection file in the Catalog tree

See [Connect to SQL Server from ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/connect-sqlserver.htm#GUID-3CF55107-6C57-4A6D-8D42-C7A1410DE1A9)

The SQL Server Native Client is available from your [My Esri](https://my.esri.com) portal.

Also see [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) - expand Install Instructions and you will find a download for the Native Client about half way down the page.  Note the 2012 Native Client is used for SQL 2014.